# How can I create implementations of interfaces, that are use specific implementations of other interfaces?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I definitely could not explain what I mean in the title. The issue is either too stupid or too complicated, but the bottom end is that I could not find an appropriate design pattern for it.

So to the point, lets assume that we have class A which contains a reference to interface B. A computational procedure determines which implementation of B is appropriate and instantiates a new object. So far so good (I think).

Now B has a method that is based on a set of parameters. Object A holds a set of default parameters but any set may be given on demand. The tricky part is that parameters are completely different among implementations of interface B. In truth these parameters are different objects themselves with their own methods, which are different per implementation of B.

My initial approach was to create an interface C for the parameters, and then create one implementation of C for each implementation of B (its a one-to-one relation), but that did not seem right. If not anything else, in each unique implementation of B, I had to cast C to the respective implementation needed to call its unique functions.

One can only assume there are prettier ways! Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

B isn't a proper interface, if its users need to call its methods with particular parameters that depend on the underlying implementation. You should rethink your design. Why does A even have access to these parameters? Do they belong in each B implementation?

Comment: Well, these are all very good questions. I'll bring an equivalent example. Assume B are shapes. They all perform the same operation, .volume(Param). Assume I don't want the obvious volume, but the volume based on some parameters, that are very different from shape to shape? Any insight on how to better model that?

Comment: Hard to know without details of what you're trying to do, but I would say for a shape, `volume` should take no parameters. If you're trying to calculate the volume of a shape, you don't want to have to provide it with something it should already know.

Comment: Well what if you want to calculate the volume after you inflate the shape with different gases under different pressures, while making different surfaces of the shape have different flexibilities and changing the gas entrance point. Since not all shapes have the same surfaces, my guess is you'd need different parameters for each. There variability is paramount, imagine for example a mesh made from spiral wiring.

Comment: Interesting example! I'm not really sure an interface is appropriate here: your code to do the inflating seems highly coupled to the type of shape. You might need a parallel hierarchy of `ShapeInflator`s, one for each type of shape (though again, perhaps the code could just live in each `Shape` implementation).

Comment: I think that is what I will do then, I will embed the class definitions of each parameter in the `Shape` implementation to avoid the parallel hierarchy. I guess considering the problem there are not many things to be done! Thanks for all the useful comments!

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in other answers, `B` is not a proper interface (in the moral sense).  If these params really can't be made part of each `B` implementation, then you could still achieve a proper interface by abstracting the details away:

```
interface BWrapper {
    public void doSomething();
}

class ConcreteB {
    public static class Params { ... }

    public class Wrapper implements BWrapper() {
        public Wrapper(Params params) { this.params = params; }
        @Override
        public void doSomething()     { ConcreteB.doSomething(params); }
        private final Params params;
    }

    public void doSomething(Params params) { ... }
}


class A {
    void setWrapper(BWrapper wrapper) { this.wrapper = wrapper; }
    void foo()                        { wrapper.doSomething(); }

    private BWrapper wrapper;
}

...

A a = new A();

ConcreteB.Params p1 = new ConcreteB.Params();
a.setWrapper(new ConcreteB.Wrapper(p1)); 
a.doSomething();

ConcreteB.Params p2 = new ConcreteB.Params();
a.setWrapper(new ConcreteB.Wrapper(p2)); 
a.doSomething();
```

Comment: So I implement each Param within its respective class, and I present that to the outside world through a wrapper containing both the implementation of B and a default Param object. Well its not most intuitive implementation ever but it if you think its right, I'll probably go for it!

Comment: @Andreas: I'm not saying that this is the only way.  It's just an example of how you can present a consistent interface without needing ugly casts.

Comment: I have two questions about this implementation. The first is that within the wrapper, I cannot do `ConcreteB.doSomething(params)` unless `doSomething` is static! Then I also wonder, why did you make `params` final?

Comment: On a more thorough look `Params` themselves need to be static, but they can not be (I think) as I need to store different params, and `doSomething` on demand based on them :/